# Install extension; marketplace on-premise

Tags: tfs

When I click on 'browse market place' for our production TFS server, it directly links to our VSTS account. If I then try to install the Sonarqube extension I only have the option to get it. 
I can install it directly for VSTS or download it for our on-premise environment.
(it behaves the same way for other extensions as well)

The strange this is that on our test on-premise environemnt I still do have the option to directly install it.
[image: Marketplace from test]
[image: Marketplace from production]

2 questions:
1) What can I reconfigure on our production env to get a connection to it in the marketplace.
2) How do I get the downloaded file into our on-premise environment?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

You could still be able to install the extension to TFS. Simply Click **get it free** option, there should be an option **download** at the bottom of the pop-up dialog.

You could then upload the locally extension to TFS server follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=tfs-2018#upload-to-team-foundation-server), finally install to your team project collection.

---

If you are **running on TFS earlier than 2017 Update 2**, you will need to **download and manually** install the latest 3.x version of the VSIX.

You can download the VSIX on the "[Releases](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-vsts/releases)" page of the GitHub repository

Versions 4.x are compatible with:

- TFS 2017 Update 2+
- TFS 2018
- VSTS

You could directly get it from server through url, and it will show as **Get it free**.

More details please take a look at this tutorial: [Analyzing with SonarQube Extension for VSTS/TFS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS)

Beside suggest you could also go through below tutorialshow to get/install extension from TFS/VSTS:

- [Install extensions for Team Foundation Server (TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts)
- [Install free extensions for VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/marketplace/install-vsts-extension?view=vsts)

Comment: We are on TFS 2018 update 1.
On our test server (exact same version) we can install the extension immediately on our on-premise collection (we then have an install button). When doing the same on the production it wants to install the extension on VSTS and I don't have an option to install it on our on-premise TFS.

Comment: @Remkop I'm afraid this may due to your have logged in your VSTS account or your network environment. The marketplace site judge you are using VSTS not on-premise TFS. However, you could still be able to install the extension to TFS. Simply Click get it free option, there should be an option **download** at the bottom of the pop-up dialog. You could then upload the extension to TFS server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=tfs-2018#upload-to-team-foundation-server, finally install to your team project collection.